# Problem in Saving a custom registration fields in Magento 1.4.2.0 DB

Tags: forms, magento, field, registration

I want to add some custom fields in the registration form and I tried to do that following the Magento Custom Account/Registration Fields and the Fontis [Adding Custom Signup Attributes](http://www.fontis.com.au/blog/magento/know-more-about-your-customers-adding-custom-signup-attributes)  but no success yet. After searching the net, it seems that something has been changed in magento new version 1.4.2.0 as these tutorials were okay in the previous versions, even 1.4.2.0 beta.

Now the actual problem is that the input data from the registration form, edit form cannot be saved into the database. It cannot be retrieved from the database. Also, the custom fields cannot appear in admin backend.

Please let us know how to get it worked successfully by adding the custom fields in magento.

I greatly appreciated it. Thanks.

~Shaman

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can no longer add registration fields in Magento 1.4.2.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4549112/can-no-longer-add-registration-fields-in-magento-1-4-2-0)

Comment: The code suggested in the "Can no longer add registration fields in Magento 1.4.2.0", where should I put them to work, please reply!

Comment: The [EAV update](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4549112/can-no-longer-add-registration-fields-in-magento-1-4-2-0/4578700#4578700) only needs to be run once so you can do this from any template, or a standalone file which also initialises Mage, or a module setup script if you are writing a custom module.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you delete the code at the point #5 from the tutorial after accessing it if you placed it in /template/customer/form/register.phtml.

The custom field won't appear in the Mangento admin, that's not covered in the tutorial.
Go into your database and check the last page of the **eav_attribute** table to see if your attribute was inserted correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Detailed information on setting up a custom attribute using the form eav model can be found here: [http://dev.turboweb.co.nz/2011/03/03/changes-to-customer-attributes](http://dev.turboweb.co.nz/2011/03/03/changes-to-customer-attributes/)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added the attribute_id for the customer_account_create in the customer_form_attribute