# Magento - Upload file during registration

Tags: php, magento, custom-fields

I want every user, that registers on my Magento instance, to upload a certificate that shows me that he registered a business.

I already added the fields in the template. But how can I fetch the file and save the filename / contents in the customer record?

Is there a way to extend the functionality in the Controllers?

Comment: community edition I take it? Pro and Enterprise have this functionality built in with customer attributes.

Comment: Yes, it is Community Edition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually even easier:

Just make sure you set these parameters on your config.xml:

```
            'attributes' => array(
                'prooffile' => array(
                    'type'          => 'text',
                    'input'         => 'file',
                    'label'         => 'Proof file',
                    'visible'       => true,
                    'required'      => false,
                    'position'      => 100,
                    "user_defined" => false,
                ),
```

This adds a nice editor in your admin backend.

Answer (score 0):

The way I did this:

I added the file field to the registration form:

```
<li class="fields">
                <div class="field">
                                <div class="input-box">
                                                <label for="prooffile"><?php echo $this->__('Proof of business registration') ?><span class="required">*</span></label><br />
                                                <input type="file" name="prooffile" id="prooffile" title="<?php echo $this->__('Proof of business registration') ?>" class="required-entry input-text" />
                                </div>
                </div>
</li>
```

Also, make sure that you set the form enctype to "multipart/form-data".

After that, I created a class that subscribes to the "user-register-success" Event. Magento has a very solid Event/Observer mechanism built in.

To do this, you have to have a custom module. In the modules etc/config.xml, add these lines for the event listener:

```
    <events>
            <customer_register_success> <!-- The name of the Event -->
                    <observers>
                            <customfields> <!-- Your module name -->
                                    <type>singleton</type>
                                    <class>customfields/observer</class> <!-- The class name, that holds your callback function -->
                                    <method>handle_file_upload</method>
                            </customfields>
                    </observers>
            </customer_register_success>
    </events>
```

This registers an event handler for the event customer_register_success. Make sure that you create a file Observer.php in your modules Model folder:

Model/Observer.php:

```
<?php

class Komola_Customfields_Model_Observer
{
        public function __construct()
        {

        }

        public function handle_file_upload($observer)
        {
                $customer = $observer->getCustomer();
                if (isset($_FILES['prooffile']['name']) && $_FILES['prooffile']['name'] != "") {
                                $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader("prooffile");
                                $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png', 'pdf'));
                                $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);
                                $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
                                $path = Mage::getBaseDir("media") . DS . "customer" . DS;
                                $logoName = $customer->getId() . "." . pathinfo($_FILES['prooffile']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                                $uploader->save($path, $logoName);
                                $customer->setProoffile($logoName);
                                $customer->save();
                }
        }
}
```

This takes the uploaded file, and saves the file in the folder media/customer (make sure to create this folder and to make it writable!). It also saves the file name in a custom customer attribute.

Comment: I had do exactly above method and save file in customer attribute. but its not uploading the file it gave me exception on line:-

$uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader("prooffile");
 
message 'File was not uploaded.'

Answer (score 0):

In the module installer file, create the attribute like this, and it will appear in the customer backend.

An extra part is needed for newer version of Magento (not sure from when exactly, but it is true as of Magento Community Edition 1.6 and up).

The "used_in_forms" key cannot be in the array passed to the addAttribute call directly (won't work). It probably contain the names of the forms from which the customer model will accept the values and not ignore them when being saved.

Known values are at this question's answers: [Can no longer add registration fields in Magento 1.4.2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4549112/can-no-longer-add-registration-fields-in-magento-1-4-2-0/4578700#4578700) (The answer by Folker Schellenberg)

I think it is the name of the controller and action that rendered the form. This name is also the main layout handle name of the page (eg: customer_account_edit).

It should be noted that the customer form in the front-end is HTML-based. It doesn't dynamically render inputs from the attributes like the backend forms. This means that if these attributes should be input by the user, the template needs to be amended to contain the proper input tags as well (and the proper value added in the used_in_forms array).

```
$attributeCode = "uploaded_file";
$attributeLabel = "Uploaded file";

$installer->addAttribute('customer', $attributeCode, array(
    'type' => 'text',
    'input' => 'file',
    'label' => $attributeLabel,
    'global' => true,
    'visible' => true,
    'required' => false,
    'user_defined' => false
));

// For newer versions of Magento, otherwise won't show up.
$eavConfig = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config');
$attribute = $eavConfig->getAttribute('customer', $attributeCode);
$attribute->setData('used_in_forms', array('customer_account_create', 'adminhtml_customer'));
$attribute->setData('sort_order', 200);
$attribute->save();
```

Another possible type is 'image' which renders exactly as 'file' except it shows the image in a preview box (a small one). Maybe good for customer photo ?

Also, noteworthy is that is this specific for the customer form (the class that handles this type of attribute is: Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Form_Element_File and Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Form_Element_Image), so this won't work in a product attribute without custom work.

Hope this helps !