# Magento add extra fields to /customer/account/create/ page

Tags: magento, field, frontend, account

I'm making great progress learning magento. My questions is, how do I add extra fields to the /customer/account/create/ page? The fields I want to add are below. Can the fields I add also appear under:

1) Frontend: Customer is able to edit/change the added fields answers in their accounts area
2) Backend: Administrator is able to see and manage the added fields under customers/manage customers/ selected customer/ customer information.

Any help or pointers is immensely appreciated.

11 OF 11
About You
WHAT IS YOUR AGE?
18-23  24-29  30-35  36-45  46-55  66+
WHAT IS YOUR HEIGHT?

WHAT IS YOUR WEIGHT?

WHAT IS YOUR ZIPCODE?

HOW DID YOU HEAR ABOUT US?
Magazine  Online  Ad  TV  Newspaper  Friend

Comment: There are lots of tutorials available on net. Check this tutorials. [Add extra fields in registration](http://magento4u.wordpress.com/2011/03/28/add-extra-fields-in-registration-page/) [Add extra fields wiki tutorial](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/customers_and_accounts/registration_fields) [Form validation](http://www.magestore.com/blog/2010/04/09/magestore-magento-tutorial-form-validation-in-magento/)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5961290/adding-attributes-to-customer-entity/5962237. See answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5961290/adding-attributes-to-customer-entity/5962237#5962237

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all your input. I came across this extension and it worked REALLY GREAT for me!
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/custom-customer-registration-fields.html

Answer (score 3):

Here is a good but old tutorial how to add custom fields in registration page
http://www.fontis.com.au/blog/magento/custom-customer-signup-attributes

It was done for Magento 1.3 so you need to read comments below the article to make it works on Magento 1.7 or check out this answer on SO [Can no longer add registration fields in Magento 1.4.2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4549112/can-no-longer-add-registration-fields-in-magento-1-4-2-0)

Also there are few extensions on Magento connect for that purpose.